# Which structure to use to recreate this Stackoverflow unit in bootstrap / css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Which structure should be used to create the following member profile unit in bootstrap.

- Table
- Div's that are floated left
- or something else?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think table style better and easy to use and its same structure in bootstrap also.